# Are XHTML tags valid in HTML?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, tags

I understand a line break in HTML is `<br>` and the XHTML equivalent is `<br />`.

I know that you **cannot** use the above HTML tag in a XHTML document, but what about vice versa? Is `<br />` valid in HTML?

Comment: it seems valid >> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp

Comment: w3schools is a terrible reference, please avoid it. See w3fools.com for a list of reasons as well as alternate resources to use in its place.

Comment: @JMax — That answer from W3Schools is *highly misleading* which puts that page in the best 50% of pages from the advert covered tutorial site that gets too much reflected glory from having a name similar to the W3C's.

Comment: I would read the page http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element ... it has a very good description of what is and isnt allowed in a void element (hint: its very lenient)

Comment: @Moses & Quentin: thanks. i'll keep your advice in mind for later comments :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends which version of HTML you are talking about.

In the latest stable version, [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/), the syntax means the same as `<br>>` which means the same as `<br>&gt;`. This means it is valid, since you can have a `>` anywhere you can have a line break, (although `<meta />` usually isn't valid) but doesn't mean what you want. Limitations in browsers (exploited by the XHTML 1.0 spec) mean that it gets treated as `<br>` even though it shouldn't be. The mess around this feature means it is marked as [to be avoided](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.3).

[HTML 5 changes that](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element) and turns the `/` into syntactic sugar. Utterly meaningless but allowed so the XML junkies are kept happy.

Answer (score 2):

`<br />` is backwards compatible and will not cause rendering problems if used in an HTML document.

Also, note that unless you are serving your documents with the MIME type `application/xhtml+xml`, putting a `<br>` in an XHTML document won't cause it to choke.  It *is* a validation error to leave a BR unclosed in an XHTML document, but a very minor one which is unlikely to cause any problems by itself.

EDIT:  Oh yes, and in HTML5 the closing `/` is once again officially optional.

Answer (score 1):

`<br />` is valid HTML. Some HTML pages may be generated by an XML engine that can't outpout `<br>`, and as such it must be able to parse it.

Comment: Can you back that up using a link to the HTML specification, maybe HTML4?

Comment: Which one of the four examples do you mean?

Comment: To parse it correctly, a visible `>` character must be rendered after each line break. Don't try to generate HTML with a non-HTML aware XML engine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes XHTML is compatible with HTML.

I believe there is one exception in HTML5 which is processing instructions like `<?xml...>` have been deprecated.